# Rivets.js bind more than once

Tags: rivets.js

I'm working with Rivets.js and want to bind to more than one data object. When I bind twice the latter bind does nothing. I've tried unbinding the first bind before attempting to bind the second data object with no luck.

Comment: Please share the code you have used so far

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/am09kxgx/2/

Comment: I found that doing a bound collection update allows me to bind a new data object. 

Example, 

    bound = rivets.bind(document.getElementById('submission'), { item: submission });

Update with new XHR data, 

    bound.update({ list: errors });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide to `rivets.bind()` an object with all your data objects (models), nested inside.

```
var data1 = { name : 'data1' };
var data2 = { name : 'data2'};
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
rivets.bind( body , { a : data1, b : data2 } );
```

To test previous binding, try with following the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>{a.name}</div>
    <div>{b.name}</div>
</body>
```